# Seaborn Heatmap with Datetime Axes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn, pandas-groupby

I and to create a heatmap that will have year across the x axis and month across the y axis. In the heatmap will be % returns. Here's kinda what I am after.

[image: heatmap]

So I have some data and I turn them into pct_change() series.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

start = dt(year = 2000, month = 1, day = 1)

df = web.DataReader('GDP', 'fred', start = '2000')
df.pct_change()
df.tail()
```

So here's what we are working with. Important to note that the index is a Datetime object.

```
    GDP
DATE    
2016-10-01  18905.545
2017-01-01  19057.705
2017-04-01  19250.009
2017-07-01  19500.602
2017-10-01  19736.491
```

I want to do something like this, but I dont know how to implement it with the datetime index

```
gdp = df.pivot(df.index.month, df.index.year, "GDP")
ax = sns.heatmap(gdp)
```

Which (expectedly) doesn't work...

```
KeyError: "Int64Index([ 1,  4,  7, 10,  1,  4,  7, 10,  1,  4,  7, 10,  1,  4,  7, 10,  1,\n             4,  7, 10,  1,  4,  7, 10,  1,  4,  7, 10,  1,  4,  7, 10,  1,  4,\n             7, 10,  1,  4,  7, 10,  1,  4,  7, 10,  1,  4,  7, 10,  1,  4,  7,\n            10,  1,  4,  7, 10,  1,  4,  7, 10,  1,  4,  7, 10,  1,  4,  7, 10,\n             1,  4,  7, 10],\n           dtype='int64', name='DATE') not in index"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working because you are extracting the month and year in place within the `pivot` function, and those information is not in the original `df` you specified.

You can specify them beforehand:

```
df["Year"] = df.DATE.apply(lambda x: x.year)
df["Month"] = df.DATE.apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%B"))
df.pivot_table(index="Month",columns="Year",values="GDP", aggfunc="sum").fillna(0)
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
pt = pt.reindex_axis(months)
sns.heatmap(pt, annot=True)
```

I'm reindexing the rows because when calling `pivot_table`, it sorts columns or rows in ascending order, which is not how the month names are usually sorted.

Above gives me:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. But, how do I add the values in the boxes??

Comment: @user2179795 Oh my bad, forgot that part. It's very easy, you only need to specify `annot=True` in heatmap function. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Sweet,  figured it was something like that. Thanks for taking a look!