# Heatmap via CSV file

Tags: csv, datetime, heatmap

I have a CSV file, with the following structure:

```
Date, time, name


01/01/2021, 09:00, Person 1

01/01/2021, 09:00, Person 2
```

There are thousands of rows in the CSV file. I was hoping to use datetime to create a heatmap with the following structure:

```
XAxis = Mon - Sun

YAxis = 00 - 23hrs
```

To represent the busiest days and times, respectively.

My brain is not functioning and I've been trying for days now. It seems simple in principle but, I can't fathom it.

Comment: you can use Seaborn library as you can see in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058347/seaborn-heatmap-with-datetime-axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058347/seaborn-heatmap-with-datetime-axes)

Comment: What environment are we talking about?

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I was trying to find a way of plotting  the heatmap without using excel but I found it quicker to create the dataframe within excel.